# CTR for a specific button that has an event label on given page from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a landing page and I want to see how many of the people who sees the page clicks a certain button.

Say that the button has an event label, e.g. "foo". How do I find out what the percentage of visitors to the page clicks the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There are two methods:-</strike>

1. Add [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for the button and then you see the data in the Events section of Google Analytics.
2. Add [campaign parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en-GB) to the URL of the button and then you can see the data in the Campaigns section of Google Analytics.

In order to obtain the % of users that either did or didn't do something on your page, you need to set 'something' up as a [goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en-GB).

You'll need to set the URL of the page that contains the button as a required step and then you'll be able to see a funnel of all visits to the page that resulted in a goal (reaching the URL the button goes to).

Comment: His question says that he already has an event label on the button.

Answer (score 1):

just a note of caution: events with page-changing buttons/links can get biased *a lot*. it's a race between the browser killing the page view (its javascript)_ and GA registering the event. so the "completed" number may be way off. I've seen up to 50% missed on form submits.

solution: using a event with callback + preventdefault handler

check this for more (and still evolving history of the problem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit